# Stack Overflow error while seeking a randomaccess file

Tags: java, file, overflow, randomaccessfile

So Im writing a program that is essentially saying whether or not a word is in the dictionary provided. The dictionary is a randomaccessfile and the index that corresponds to the dictionary is also a randomaccessfile. Both files are quite large.

I'm using a recursive binary search to check to see if the word is in the dictionary. When I do indexFile.lenth()/4 to get the max length of the index, then calculate the mid and do indexFile.seek(4*mid) I get a stack overflow error and I dont understand why

```
long mid = (max - min)/2;
indexFile.seek(4*mid);
int wordposition = indexFile.readInt();
int nextword = indexFile.readInt();
int wordlength = (nextword - wordposition)/2;
wordsFile.seek(wordposition);
String finalword = "";
for(int i=0; i<wordlength;i++);
{
    finalword = finalword + wordsFile.readChar();
}

if (word.equals(finalword))
{
    return word;
}
else if (finalword.compareTo(word) > 0)
{
     binarysearch(word, min, (mid - 1));
}
else
{
    binarysearch(word, (mid+1), max); 
    System.out.println("yoooo");
}

if (min > max)
{ return "Word not found";}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that means sorry! Can you elaborate. I did some checking with prints and i dont think the "wordlength" part is working, does that part of the code seem right?

Comment: Try `long mid = (max + min)/2;` instead.

Comment: @EvanKnowles Jeez I am an idiot haha that is definitely right. Unfortunately my wordlength part is still not working, for some reason when I'm testing what finalword is printing out after each recursive call, its just printing one character, any idea why?

Comment: We'd need to see an example of how your files are laid out.

Comment: I figured it out! somehow hah, I just deleted and retyped part of the code and it works so I must have just had some small mistake